# Easy racer tour easy frame seat?

Tags: recumbent

New on this site,I would like to know where to go for replace seat frame on a tour easy recumbent ! Many Thanks!

Comment: Probably worth reading the [tour] to learn how a Q&A site works and what's considered off topic.  This is a shopping question and is also strongly regional - you wouldn't want an French answer if you live in Australia.  I'd suggest you start with googling for "easy tour recumbent seat site:fr"   to restrict results to French sites for example.   Or you could try the manufacturer at   https://easyracers.com/contact.html

Comment: If your seat frame is broken, but repairable, then post that as a fresh question with photos.

Comment: Sun (house brand of major US bike wholesaler J&B Importers) still makes their licensed versions of the Easyracers design. I have no idea whether the seat mounting is close enough to be a match, but they do have replacement parts available. Any bike shop in the US can get them. https://www.jbi.bike/site/search_usd.php?x1=BICYCLE+REP+PARTS&x2=RECUMBENT+PARTS&x3=SEAT+PARTS#BICYCLE+REP+PARTS_RECUMBENT+PARTS_SEAT+PARTS